# How to capture log level Error and Warning both in Pyspark?

Tags: python, logging, pyspark

I have tried to set log level as `error` or `warn`, but curious how to capture both ?

I have tried in pyspark

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
```

In `Debug` I am getting lot of extra information and so is with `info` or `default`,
would appreciate if anyone can suggest a better solution for getting errors and warning only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set it to `WARN` it will capture `ERROR` as well.

It's a hierarchical log level structure.

- `ERROR` is a above `WARN` in the hierarchy, so `WARN` logs will be ignored if `LogLevel` set to `ERROR`. 
  But since `WARN` is below `ERROR` in the hierarchy, and you set the `LogLevel` to `WARN`, it will show you `ERROR` logs as well.